# Server Error in '/' Application. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Set'. 'bit' is not a recognized SET option

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-4.5, server-error

I'm trying to build a very basic asp.net webpage that connects to an Azure database containing  vaccine info. I have a dropdown list that initially filters on the vaccine which then pulls related data for that vaccine in a gridview.

I have also included a dropdown list that appears when I click to update the row.  This second dropdown list allows me to change the vaccine type and appears in the vaccine column of the gridview.

At this point, all works.  It is after I click edit, change the vaccine name from the list, and then click the update link that a few issues occur.  It should be noted there is an "Active Data Set" column that uses the "bit" data type in the table being accessed/updated.

The first issue I receive is: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Set'.

Everything looks right in the statements, so any help here would be much appreciated.

Second issue: 'bit' is not a recognized SET option. Incorrect syntax near ','.
'bit' is not a recognized SET option. Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I believe there is an issue between the bit type in SQL and the boolean type in C#.  And, while I have found discussions around this, I don't know for certain if this is the issue or how to tackle it.

Also note, while the code exists for Insert and Delete, neither is being used at this time (i.e. no buttons/links to click).  It was auto-generated and I have left it in for the time being.

Explicit answers/suggestions would be appreciated as this is a new venture for me.  Error message (click to enlarge) and code follows.

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="MasterDetails" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>PAHO Price Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <h1>Details Page</h1>

    </div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="ProductSubTypeName" DataValueField="ProductSubTypeId">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Market_InsightsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductSubTypeId], [ProductSubTypeName] FROM [ProductSubType]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PriceId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PriceId" HeaderText="PriceId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PriceId" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vaccine" SortExpression="ProductSubTypeName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AutoGenerateRows="False"
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="ProductSubTypeName" DataValueField="ProductSubTypeName"
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProductSubTypeName") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductSubTypeName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryName" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="CountryName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PriceYear" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="PriceYear" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Presentation" HeaderText="Presentation" SortExpression="Presentation" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="column1" HeaderText="Doses/Vial" SortExpression="Doses/Vial" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MarketTypeName" HeaderText="Market Type" SortExpression="MarketTypeName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="column2" HeaderText="Price/Dose (USD)" SortExpression="Price/Dose (USD)" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Source" HeaderText="Source" SortExpression="Source" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Comment" HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="Comment" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PriceSourceTypeName" HeaderText="Price Source Type" SortExpression="PriceSourceTypeName" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active Data Set" HeaderText="Active Data Set" SortExpression="Active Data Set" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DataSource" HeaderText="DataSource" SortExpression="DataSource" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date of Published Update" HeaderText="Date of Published Update" SortExpression="Date of Published Update" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastModifiedBy" HeaderText="LastModifiedBy" SortExpression="LastModifiedBy" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastModifiedDate" HeaderText="LastModifiedDate" SortExpression="LastModifiedDate" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Market_InsightsConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="
            DELETE FROM [Price_PAHO] 
            WHERE [PriceId] = @original_PriceId 
                AND [ProductSubTypeId] = @original_ProductSubTypeId 
                AND (([CountryId] = @original_CountryId) OR ([CountryId] IS NULL AND @original_CountryId IS NULL)) 
                AND [PriceYear] = @original_PriceYear 
                AND (([Presentation] = @original_Presentation) OR ([Presentation] IS NULL AND @original_Presentation IS NULL)) 
                AND (([Doses/Vial] = @original_column1) OR ([Doses/Vial] IS NULL AND @original_column1 IS NULL)) 
                AND (([MarketTypeId] = @original_MarketTypeId) OR ([MarketTypeId] IS NULL AND @original_MarketTypeId IS NULL)) 
                AND (([Price/Dose (USD)] = @original_column2) OR ([Price/Dose (USD)] IS NULL AND @original_column2 IS NULL)) 
                AND (([Source] = @original_Source) OR ([Source] IS NULL AND @original_Source IS NULL)) 
                AND (([Comment] = @original_Comment) OR ([Comment] IS NULL AND @original_Comment IS NULL)) 
                AND [PriceSourceTypeId] = @original_PriceSourceTypeId 
                AND [Active Data Set] = @original_Active_Data_Set 
                AND [DataSource] = @original_DataSource 
                AND (([Date of Published Update] = @original_Date_of_Published_Update) OR ([Date of Published Update] IS NULL AND @original_Date_of_Published_Update IS NULL)) 
                AND [LastModifiedBy] = @original_LastModifiedBy 
                AND [LastModifiedDate] = @original_LastModifiedDate" 
        InsertCommand="
            INSERT INTO [Price_PAHO] (
                [ProductSubTypeId]
                , [CountryId]
                , [PriceYear]
                , [Presentation]
                , [Doses/Vial]
                , [MarketTypeId]
                , [Price/Dose (USD)]
                , [Source]
                , [Comment]
                , [PriceSourceTypeId]
                , [Active Data Set]
                , [DataSource]
                , [Date of Published Update]
                , [LastModifiedBy]
                , [LastModifiedDate]) 
            VALUES (
                @ProductSubTypeId
                , @CountryId
                , @PriceYear
                , @Presentation
                , @column1
                , @MarketTypeId
                , @column2
                , @Source
                , @Comment
                , @PriceSourceTypeId
                , @Active_Data_Set
                , @DataSource
                , @Date_of_Published_Update
                , @LastModifiedBy
                , @LastModifiedDate)" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        SelectCommand="
            SELECT pah.PriceId
                , pst.ProductSubTypeName
                , cou.CountryName
                , pah.PriceYear
                , pah.[Doses/Vial] AS [column1]
                , mar.MarketTypeName
                , pah.[Price/Dose (USD)] AS [column2]
                , pah.Presentation
                , pah.Source
                , pah.Comment
                , pri.PriceSourceTypeName
                , (CASE
                    WHEN pah.[Active Data Set] = 1 THEN 'TRUE'
                    ELSE 'FALSE'
                  END) AS [Active Data Set]
                , pah.DataSource
                , pah.[Date of Published Update]
                , pah.LastModifiedBy
                , pah.LastModifiedDate 
            FROM Price_PAHO AS pah 
            INNER JOIN ProductSubType AS pst ON pah.ProductSubTypeId = pst.ProductSubTypeId 
            INNER JOIN Country AS cou ON pah.CountryId = cou.CountryId 
            INNER JOIN MarketType AS mar ON pah.MarketTypeId = mar.MarketTypeId 
            INNER JOIN PriceSourceType AS pri ON pah.PriceSourceTypeId = pri.PriceSourceTypeId 
            WHERE (pah.ProductSubTypeId = @ProductSubTypeId)" 
        UpdateCommand="
            UPDATE [Price_PAHO] 
            SET [ProductSubTypeId] = @ProductSubTypeId
                , [CountryId] = @CountryId
                , [PriceYear] = @PriceYear
                , [Presentation] = @Presentation
                , [Doses/Vial] = @column1
                , [MarketTypeId] = @MarketTypeId
                , [Price/Dose (USD)] = @column2
                , [Source] = @Source
                , [Comment] = @Comment
                , [PriceSourceTypeId] = @PriceSourceTypeId
                , [Active Data Set] = @Active_Data_Set
                , [DataSource] = @DataSource
                , [Date of Published Update] = @Date_of_Published_Update
                , [LastModifiedBy] = @LastModifiedBy
                , [LastModifiedDate] = @LastModifiedDate 
            WHERE [PriceId] = @original_PriceId 
                AND [ProductSubTypeId] = @original_ProductSubTypeId 
                AND (([CountryId] = @original_CountryId) 
                OR ([CountryId] IS NULL AND @original_CountryId IS NULL)) 
                AND [PriceYear] = @original_PriceYear 
                AND (([Presentation] = @original_Presentation) 
                OR ([Presentation] IS NULL AND @original_Presentation IS NULL)) 
                AND (([Doses/Vial] = @original_column1) 
                OR ([Doses/Vial] IS NULL AND @original_column1 IS NULL)) 
                AND (([MarketTypeId] = @original_MarketTypeId) 
                OR ([MarketTypeId] IS NULL AND @original_MarketTypeId IS NULL)) 
                AND (([Price/Dose (USD)] = @original_column2) 
                OR ([Price/Dose (USD)] IS NULL AND @original_column2 IS NULL)) 
                AND (([Source] = @original_Source) 
                OR ([Source] IS NULL AND @original_Source IS NULL)) 
                AND (([Comment] = @original_Comment) 
                OR ([Comment] IS NULL AND @original_Comment IS NULL)) 
                AND [PriceSourceTypeId] = @original_PriceSourceTypeId 
                AND [Active Data Set] = @original_Active_Data_Set 
                AND [DataSource] = @original_DataSource 
                AND (([Date of Published Update] = @original_Date_of_Published_Update) 
                OR ([Date of Published Update] IS NULL AND @original_Date_of_Published_Update IS NULL)) 
                AND [LastModifiedBy] = @original_LastModifiedBy 
                AND [LastModifiedDate] = @original_LastModifiedDate">
         <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_PriceId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ProductSubTypeId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_CountryId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_PriceYear" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Presentation" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_column1" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_MarketTypeId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_column2" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Source" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Comment" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_PriceSourceTypeId" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Active_Data_Set" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_DataSource" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="original_Date_of_Published_Update" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_LastModifiedBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_LastModifiedDate" Type="DateTime" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProductSubTypeId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CountryId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PriceYear" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Presentation" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="column1" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="MarketTypeId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="column2" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Source" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Comment" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PriceSourceTypeId" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Active_Data_Set" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DataSource" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Date_of_Published_Update" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastModifiedBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastModifiedDate" Type="DateTime" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="ProductSubTypeId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProductSubTypeId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CountryId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PriceYear" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Presentation" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="column1" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="MarketTypeId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="column2" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Source" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Comment" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PriceSourceTypeId" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Active_Data_Set" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DataSource" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Date_of_Published_Update" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastModifiedBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastModifiedDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_PriceId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ProductSubTypeId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_CountryId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_PriceYear" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Presentation" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_column1" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_MarketTypeId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_column2" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Source" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Comment" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_PriceSourceTypeId" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Active_Data_Set" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_DataSource" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="original_Date_of_Published_Update" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_LastModifiedBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_LastModifiedDate" Type="DateTime" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

Comment: TL:DR; but There is suspect here. In the SELECT you convert the BIT value to a string TRUE/FALSE but in the INSERT/UPDATE you pretend this to be a boolean. Not sure if things are related but I would try to temporarily remove that conversion and let the column be a boolean. Just to see what happens

Comment: Yeah, I did that as a bit of a test as a suggestion found on a post for someone else with a related issue.  The problem remains either way...